# delete node in BST

Tags: c, free, binary-search-tree, treenode

I have problem with delete node function in BST. I tested all other function works fine but if i print tree after deleting an node it causes segmentation fault.
Here is my code for deletion:

```
struct Tree * findinorder (struct Tree *t)
{
   while (t->lchild != NULL)
         t=t->lchild;
   return t;       
}

bool deleteNode (struct Tree *t, int fvalue)
{
 bool find = false; //this is to check if node is already found don't go to right sub tree
 struct Tree *inorder;
 if (t==NULL) return find;
 if (t->value == fvalue)
 {
    if (t->lchild == NULL && t->rchild == NULL )
    {
       free(t);
    }
    else {
         if (t->lchild ==NULL)
            t= t->rchild;
         else {
            if (t->rchild ==NULL)
               t= t->lchild;
            else {
                       inorder = findinorder(t->rchild);
                       t->value = inorder->value;
                       free(inorder);
            }
         }
    }
    return true;
 }
 find = deleteNode(t->lchild, fvalue);
 if (!find)
    find = deleteNode(t->rchild, fvalue);
 return find;   
}
```

here is tree structure and function for printing:

```
struct Tree
{
   int value;
   struct Tree *lchild;
   struct Tree *rchild;       
}*root;

void print (struct Tree *t)
{
    if (!t) return;
    if(t->lchild != NULL)
                 print(t->lchild);  

    printf("%d\n",t->value);             

    if(t->rchild != NULL)
                 print(t->rchild);
}
```

My suspect is some how node is not set to null which causing problem in print and it goes on.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep a pointer to the previous node so that you can update the new references to `rchild` / `lchild` accordingly:

[image]

imagine `node` to be a pointer to 5, the removal (in this concrete case) should look more like:

```
if (node->rchild && node->rchild->value == 21) {
    struct Tree *child = node->rchild;
    node->rchild = child->rchild;             // <-- update reference
    free(child);
}
```

But look at the node 21 and think of what should happen upon its removal? ...The code should be more complex than just calling `free` on a pointer to node once it is found :)

What happens in your case is that you `free` the appropriate node, but once you traverse it after that, the pointer to the node that has previously been `free`d is used, which yields ***undefined behavior***.